# Why are my fetch requests between my react app and express server not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express

I am trying to link up my react js front end (hosted on localhost currently / for testing, but getting the same error on my s3 bucket instance of the same react app) to by node js / express server (hosted on an elastic beanstalk environment on AWS). I recently added headers to my fetch requests in my react app to get past a cors error. Here is an example of what I did:

```
validateUser = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
fetch('https://myServerURL/signIn?username=' + this.state.validateUsername + '&password=' + this.state.validatePassword, 
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'
    })
  }
)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
  console.log('testing' + response.userID)
  this.setState({test: response.userID})
})
  }
```

I also have the following cors configuration code in my node / express server (these are my first few line in my express server):

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
var cors = require("cors")
const formData = require("express-form-data");
const { PORT = 8080 } = process.env

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(formData.parse({maxFieldSize: '10mb'}));
```

I am now getting a different cors error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://myServerURL/signIn?username=****&password=****' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

This 'Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request' error seems much less common than my last cors error (which was dealing with the lack of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in my react app), and I am having trouble finding solutions / documentation to it.. I am at a loss as to what to do to fix this error. For a little bit of context, incase it is of importance:

1. I created rules in AWS Route53 to route traffic from my own custom domain name to the elastic beanstalk url. I believe this was necessary to utilize my SSL certificate, which assisted with an https to http error (communicating from my s3 bucket url to my EB url).
2. I do not think all this routing and configuration is causing my cors issue, but I am unsure so I wanted to include it as context.

Am I missing configuration details in my react app in my headers? Or is there something missing in my express server (I was under the impression that enabling the cors module "takes care of" the server side issues of cors...)?

Again, to clarify, this is my error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

I have researched this error until I'm blue in the face and am at my wits end. What is causing this error and how do I fix it? Thanks so much for the help.

---

UPDATE

---

When I change the fetch url from my domain name (which is an https domain routing to my EB url) to the url of the EB environment, the application works fine. So it seems the cors error may be coming from the way I am routing the traffic? Please help!!

Comment: One issue is the headers you're attempting to pass from the client, e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` are only allowed to be set on the server.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try moving your **frontend** headers to the **backend** with the **cors** setup like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token")
  app.use(cors());
  next();
});
```

Don't forget to remove those headers from the frontend code.

Comment: This did not work. It created a different error, which I was avoiding by having that header information in my react app: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.